# Return a list using viewmodel(or commandResult)

Tags: c#, list, collections, command, viewmodel

I have a HttpGet endpoint, and it should return a collection of transfers, I'm using my Entity `Transfer` to do that

[image]

but I'm trying to change to use my CommandResponse(or viewmodel) `GetTransferResponse`, and I don't know how to use my var `transfer` in my CommandResponse

[image]

I already use it when it's only one transfer, but with a collection, I Don't know how create the constructor in this case, I think it's going to looks like this, but it's going to be a collection:

[image]

my repository:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extension methods to convert `ICollection<Transfer>` to `ICollection<GetTransferResponse>`.

Make sure to include:

`using System.Linq;`

Update your `GetAll` method to:

```
public ICollection<GetTransferResponse> GetAll()
{
    var transfer = _repo.GetAll()
                        .Select(x => new GetTransferResponse(x))
                        .ToList();
    return transfer;
}
```

Comment: If this answers your question. Can you please upvote and mark it as answer. This might help others.

Comment: i can't upvote because my reputation is under 15, but I mark as answer